# How to create a sequence number in excel using based on two columns with primary and secondary key

Tags: excel

I am trying to generate a sequence number in excel based on two columns.
The input data (Column A and Column B) I have looks like this, I want to achieve the sequence in column C

***Excel:***
[image]

I have tried `IF()` and `Countif()` in Excel

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula-

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B2,$A$2:$A2=A2)))
```

For dynamic spill result. Use below formula-

```
=MAP(A2:A14,LAMBDA(x,COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B14,($A$2:$A14=x)*(ROW(A2:A14)<=ROW(x)))))))
```

[image]